# How to avoid using subquery in this situation Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Hi I have a situation where I need to Join two tables but filter value from a third table. As below:

```
SELECT a.Key , (SELECT SUM(B.hours) FROM tableB as B 
                 INNER JOIN tableC as C ON B.List=C.List 
                 WHERE C.Status = 'Approved' AND B.Key LIKE A.key) , 
               (SELECT SUM(B.hours) FROM tableB as B 
                 INNER JOIN tableC as C ON B.List=C.List 
                 WHERE C.Status = 'Pending' AND B.Key LIKE A.key) 
FROM tableA as A GROUP BY A.key
```

is there another way to do this without using correlated subqueries? i'd like to use joins , but i just don't know how to link table C into this picture.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subquery may not be such a bad idea, but you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.Key,
       sum(iif(c.Status = "Approved", B.hours, 0)),
       sum(iif(c.Status = "Pending", B.hours, 0))
FROM tableA as A left join
     (tableB as b inner join
      tableC as c
      on b.list = c.list
     ) 
     on b.key like a.key
GROUP BY A.key;
```

MS Access has arcane syntax for joins, particularly for multiple joins.  I think the above is correct.

Comment: thanks Gordon, I didn't know Access permit joining child tables with child tables. ie I thought Access only allow Table A Join Table B, and Table Join Table C . Not like your answer Table A Join table B, then inside (table B join table C) . I am going to try it right now and get back to you.

Comment: @Tyrion . . . Access *does* allow it.  I'm just never sure if I get the Access syntax right.  I tend to avoid Access, preferring free versions of other databases instead.

Comment: well the brackets gave me a headache, especially as i had to join other tables. but it worked!. Thank you very much.